# SQLAlchemy: IntegrityError when trying to fill polymorphic table with duplicate entries

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy, polymorphic-associations

I have the below code where I'm using sqlalchemy to create a databse structure.
When a person either changes their profession, location or salary, I would like to
fill in the `questionnaires` table with their new profession, location or salary.
Depending on what has changed the `type` in `questionnaires` should be either `profession`, `location` or `salary` and the `value` is the corresponding value.

I also have a table `addresses` (with addresses and locations, there is a one to one relationship between address and location) and a table `professions`. Those two tables should not have any duplicates (hence the `unique=True`) but the `questionnaires` table can have duplicates.

When I try to fill in some values into these tables I get an `IntegrityError` when trying to commit `location_instance` as `location2` already exists in the addresses table. This is as I would like to have it. If I try to commit `questionnaire_location`
though I also get an `IntegrityError` which should not be (as there can and should be duplicates in `questionnaires`).
How can I make this work? Maybe there is also another option than using `IntegrityError`?

What I would like is to have duplicates in `questionnaires` but not in `addresses`and also not in `professions`.

```
import dotenv
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.exc import IntegrityError


########### models ###########
Base = declarative_base()

class Profession(Base):
    __tablename__ = "professions"

    id                = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    profession        = Column(String, nullable=True, index=True, unique=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"""<Profession(
          profession={self.profession}
          )>"""
    
class Address(Base):
    __tablename__ = "addresses"

    id        = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    address     = Column(String, nullable=True, index=True, unique=True)
    location  = Column(String, nullable=True, index=True, unique=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"""<Address(
          address={self.address}, 
          location={self.location})>"""
        
class Questionnaire(Base):
    __tablename__ = "questionnaires"

    id                  = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    current_address          = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("addresses.id"),  nullable=False, index=True)
    type = Column(String, nullable=False)  #'location', 'profession', 'salary'
    value = Column(String, nullable=False)  #value corresponding to the type

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'questionnaire',
        'polymorphic_on': type
    }

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"""<Questionnaire(
          current_address={self.current_address}, 
          type={self.type}, 
          value={self.value})>"""
    
class ProfessionQuestionnaire(Questionnaire):
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': 'profession'}

    profession_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('professions.id'))

    profession = relationship("Profession")

class LocationQuestionnaire(Questionnaire):
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': 'location'}

    location_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('addresses.id'))

    location = relationship("Address", foreign_keys=[location_id])



########### create empty tables ###########
dotenv.load_dotenv()
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL = "sqlite:///./dwh/database.db"

engine = create_engine(
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL, 
    connect_args={"check_same_thread": False},
)
SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)

Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine) 
db = SessionLocal()  



########### fill tables ###########
###professions table
for profession in ['teacher', 'actor', 'waiter', 'home maker']:
    to_add = Profession(profession=profession)
    db.add(to_add)
    try:
        db.commit()
    except IntegrityError as e:
        db.rollback()
        print(f"IntegrityError: {e}")    

###addresses table
for address, location in zip(['address1', 'address2', 'address3', 'address4'], ['location1', 'location2', 'location3', 'location4']):
    to_add = Address(address=address, location=location)
    db.add(to_add)
    try:
        db.commit()
    except IntegrityError as e:
        db.rollback()
        print(f"IntegrityError: {e}")    

###questionnaires table
#profession
profession = 'real estate agent'
profession_instance = Profession(profession=profession)
questionnaire_profession = ProfessionQuestionnaire(current_address='address1', value=profession, profession=profession_instance)

#location
location = 'location2'
location_instance = Address(location=location)
questionnaire_location = LocationQuestionnaire(current_address='address1', value=location, location=location_instance)

#salary
questionnaire_salary = Questionnaire(current_address='address1', type='salary', value='200')

for to_add in [profession_instance, location_instance, questionnaire_profession, questionnaire_location, questionnaire_salary]:
    db.add(to_add) 
    try:
        db.commit()
    except IntegrityError as e:
        db.rollback()
        print(f"IntegrityError: {e}")
```